# Upsert from ADF to Salesforce writes a record when no changes

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, upsert

I am creating a copy activity that pulls information from ADF and I want it to upsert into an object in Salesforce.  The activity is working, I saw the record get created, and it changes if I modify my query.  IE:  add a date, date is in Salesforce, remove it, date is removed.

However, when I check the activity in ADF I see a row was written when there are no changes.  Is this correct?  I apologize I am new to the ADF Upsert and want to verify it is running correctly.

[image]

I created a copy activity.  I am expecting it to read a row but not write one when there are no changes.  Unless I am mistaken as to how upsert works with Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

So basically an upsert is a combination of update or else insert. When a row is pulled from azure sql into salesforce, update or insert operation does not matter for the activity summary as for the categorization, and either action will be recorded as "written". So this is by design.

Here is a post in MSFT forums regarding a similar question, the responder suggests creating temporal tables to see whats happening in sink:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/961348/how-to-tell-if-insert-or-update-was-done-using-cop

Hope my answer helped, sorry for the confusion.